# Joomla return URL when login sent via email

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, url, redirect

I created following URL (that I am sending via email to the user):

> $form->data['redirect_url'] = urlencode(base64_encode("http://www.domain.it/" . $form->data['link_form'] . "?id_risposta=" . $form->data['id_risposta']));
>
> $form->data['link_modifica_bozza'] = "http://www.domain.it/component/users/?view=login&return=" . $form->data['redirect_url'];

This means that after login the user will be redirect to "redirect_url".

The problem is that if the user is already logged in, it is stacked in profile page, and it is not redirect to "redirect_url" automatically.

Is there any way to add an automatic redirect directly in the URL if the user is already logged in?

Like a conditional URL...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and I have solved it as follows:

1. In Joomla, you can create a Menu with Access "Registered",
2. When you send a link with this Menu, the user will automatically gets a login page and redirected afterwards to this site.

Btw, if you need to show that menu, you can create a hidden menu first (with "registered" access), and add an "Menu Item Alias" (System Links) to this hidden menu. You can test it on my site with e.g.
https://www.loytec.com/support-en/rma

When the user is not logged in, the standard log-in process is shown; if the user is already logged-in, it directs to the menu.

Comment: Unfortunately for me it is not a static URL...

Comment: I mean, it is a very good idea, but I am creating a dynamic link and I send it via email (e.g. url.com?par=1). I need the user logged in and then redirected to that dynamic link... Any idea?